# How to define space between two horizontal buttons?

Tags: java, css, gwt

I have two buttons and don't want them to be aligned with a space between them. But the following does not work:

```
<gwt:FlowPanel styleName="{style.pad}">
    <gwt:Button text="foo" />
    <gwt:Button text="bar" />
</gwt:FlowPanel>

<ui:style>
    .pad .gwt-Button {
            margin-right: 20px !important;
    }
</ui:style>
```

Result: buttons are aligned side by side, no space between them. Why??

Comment: try padding:20px; in the css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it: I had to use `@external gwt-Button;` in the ui:style declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.gwt-Button {

padding : 10px !important

}
```

Comment: Hm does not change anything...

Comment: Delete the cache and then try... It will work

Comment: I did, and I also tried a different browser. nothing changed...